# How can I open an InfoPath form template from a web part in Sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint, infopath

I have several Infopath form templates on my sharepoint site.  Normally, I have to go to each library, then click "Add document" to open InfoPath.  Instead, I would like to build a web part that displays all of the titles (of the forms and therefore of the libraries) and open Infopath with one click on the form name.  How can I do this?

Comment: I suggest you have a look at
http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/ and if you don't find anything, then post your question there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to solve this is by creating a Content Editor WebPart in which you add links to the forms.

1) Go to the library you want to add and click the "add" button
2) Copy the url of the newly opened page (InfoPath form)
3) Add a new hyperlink to the CEWP and paste the url

Repeat this steps for all lists.